# I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that

Tags: discussion

I wondering how serious do all of out tags have to be?  Many/most certainly could use a very good and serious answer.  However, I was having a little fun with 'computer' and for the Excerpt put in "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."  (HAL 9000) because I didn't think that particular tag needed a serious explanation.

I thought it might be kind of fun to have a few like this here and there if the tag seemed obvious enough, and the expanded text could still have a 'good' answer.  Thoughts? Opinions?  I bring this up of course because that and one other I was having fun with were rejected so thought I'd ask.

Comment: I chuckled then rejected I'm afraid

Comment: The problem is that such "jokes" inspire others, and most people are just not that funny.

Comment: it's not a problem, I just really wanted to know what the expectations were.

Comment: Perhaps the topic no longer has much relevance, but I have edited the phrase out of the tag wiki.

Answer (score 7):

### Tags are Serious Business.

Tags are one of the essential sorting mechanisms that we use to connect questions with experts and solutions with users. Relatively few SE users read all the documentation, so the *practice* of tagging (including how we write tag wikis) is the primary way they learn how the system works.

If every user was well-educated about tags, tag jokes might be more feasible. However, because tags are so crucial to the Stack Exchange 'pile of well-sorted questions and answers' goal, we really should make sure that tags model behaviour.

### So do the Serious Stuff first, *then* add levity

That said, if you slip a reference like this into a tag wiki that *also* has all the useful and necessary tag wiki content, that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 6):

I fully agree with [BESW's answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/492/29) in that **tags are not something that we should joke about.**

That said, I also want to add two things.

First, personally **I would also have rejected that [tag wiki excerpt edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2225) outright** since it doesn't do anything to aid anyone in knowing when to use the [computers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) tag. A better tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt would have discussed how we use and expect users to use that tag; *for example,* does it pertain only to electronic computers, or are questions about mechanical computers acceptable (cue someone perhaps asking about situations which might lead a civilization to develop [difference engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_engine) but never advance beyond that)? What about [the concept of computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer#Etymology) without involving the use of any particular invention? And so on. There are *many* nuances to such a tag that can *and should* be captured in the tag wiki, in order to guide people on how and when to use the particular tag.

Second, the edit was rejected by [the director of Community Development for Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52/robert-cartaino). That alone should tell plenty.

Comment: assume ignorance not malice

Comment: @bowlturner Assume I not. Explain, I do.